# jscrollpane plugin - the slider covers the arrows

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I'm using the jscrollpane plugin for a scroll bar. The slider covers the arrows of the scrollbar when it arrives at the end of it. An example is here: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrow_positions.html. How can I change this? I want to have the arrow image showing even when the slider is in this position.

In the second example picture the up arrow is covered.

[image]  [image]

Comment: can't see problem on demo page, can you make a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.jspArrowUp.jspDisabled background was not set.